# Edit Form Control Label Caption on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to edit the text of a form control label named `lblsearchreminder` and make sure that the font is Arial and size 20. I am pulling the edited text from an ActiveX textbox1 and trying to make that the caption of the label. If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Sub btnAltCustomSearch_Click()

    Dim strTextBox As String

    If Worksheets("User Interface").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = "" Then
        ErrorX.Show
    Else
        strTextBox = Worksheets("User Interface").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value
        Worksheets("Muscle Wasting Database").Shapes("lblsearchreminder") = vbCrLf & "Disease: All" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Keyword: " & strTextBox
        lblsearchreminder.Object.Characters.Text = "Arial"
        lblsearchreminder.Object.Font.Size = 20

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I presume the problem is that the font of `lblsearchreminder` isn't set to `Arial` and font size isn't set to `20` points? Are you getting an error by any chance? #438 member not found on `.Object.Characters.Text`? Or something else? Also `Error` is a function in the `VBA.Conversion` module that you're shadowing with that `Error` control - might want to rename it.

Comment: Is it a `.ListObject` or a `Label`?

Comment: `TextBox1` doesn't seem like a plausible default name for a **Form** control, given `TextBox` (Text Field) has long been deprecated. What Excel version are you running, or can you please confirm that you're using an **ActiveX** `TextBox` control?

Comment: Yes the textbox1 is an ActiveX textbox control, but I will ideally use a Form Control label. So I am trying to pull the typing from the ActiveX textbox and use it in the Form Control label

Comment: Posted an answer. You may want to refresh the page...

Answer (score 2):

> > Yes the textbox1 is an ActiveX textbox control, but I will ideally use a Form Control label. So I am trying to pull the typing from the ActiveX textbox and use it in the **Form Control label** – Thor Nagel 3 hours ago

Unfortunately you can't manipulate the font-size/name, color or style of a Form Control Label.  If you notice the formatting items have been "grayed out" in the Font group on the Excel Ribbon.

[image]

To set a Text is easy

```
Dim lblsearchreminder As Shape
Set lblsearchreminder = Sheet1.Shapes("Label 1")
lblsearchreminder.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello"
```

But you cannot do (**Even though Intellisense allows it**)

```
lblsearchreminder.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Arial"
```

or

```
lblsearchreminder.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = "Arial"
```

I would recommend using a `TextBox` shape or an `ActiveX Label` instead.

Similarly you cannot change the font using

```
lblsearchreminder.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size= 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're using a *Form Control*. `TextBox1` would be the default name for an **ActiveX** control, which would be coherent with using `.OLEObject.Object` to retrieve it.

Declare a `MSForms.TextBox` variable for it.

```
Dim box As MSForms.TextBox
```

Now assign it to the `.OLEObject.Object`:

```
Set box =  Worksheets("User Interface").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
```

If the sheet "User Interface" exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, give it a *code name* (F4; set the `(Name)` property to e.g. `UserInterfaceSheet`) - then you can use that identifier directly, without needing to pull the worksheet from the `Worksheets` collection:

```
Set box = UserInterfaceSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
```

Now you have an early-bound object reference to play with, you'll have *IntelliSense* to guide you. `MSForms.TextBox` does not have a `.Characters` property. It *does* have a `.Font` property though, so you can start exploring that:

[image: Object Browser showing members of MSForms.TextBox]

So the `Font` property is an object of type `NewFont`; using the Object Browser (F2) you can browse its members:

[image: Object Browser showing members of MSForms.NewFont]

Thus:

```
box.Font.Name = "Arial"
box.Font.Size = 20
```

Should do it.

---

Watch out for misleading names and prefixes: `lblsearchreminder` reads like you're looking at a `MSForms.Label` control, not a `TextBox`. `txtSearchReminder` would be more appropriate, or if you prefer control-agnostic names, `SearchReminderBox` works as well.

Also `Error` is a function from the `VBA.Conversion` module, that you are [*shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) here.

Comment: Hey mathieu really appreciate the help -- I think I maybe misspoke a little out of lack of understanding since I have been teaching myself VBA. I am trying to take the string that is typed into the ActiveX text box and put it into a form control label that has Arial font and size 20 text. I have tried to interpret your answer and apply it to this problem but I am unsure if it is possible.

Comment: That isn't what your code tries to do, and isn't what your question (which still needs to be edited with clarifications) asks about, assuming it's asking something - I posted this answer hoping it would be useful, but your question is unanswerable as it stands, and your code is very, very, *very* confusing - `lblsearchreminder` seems to be a `ListObject`, i.e. a *table*, which doesn't have a `Caption` property. Use the worksheet's `Shapes` collection to find your label.